# Vim deleted all occurrences of match, when not told to do so

Tags: linux, vim

I am using vim editor and it deletes all occurrences of given word `foo` for the following command:

```
%s/foo//
```

Note that I have not used the global operator here. Can anyone please help resolving this ?

Comment: What is the output of `:echo &gdefault`?

Comment: HI,
It is giving output as 0

Comment: That's interesting. Can we see a simple example reproducible with `$ vim -Nu NONE`?

Comment: Do you mean: 1) several occurrences of 'foo' appearing on the same line or 2) several occurrences of 'foo' appearing on different lines (but only ONCE per line)? _number 2) would be expected behaviour, but number 1) would be strange_

Comment: I am encountering case-2, what should be done to only delete foo from first line

Answer (score 0):

The "%" range covers all lines, i.e. the whole file.

The "g" flag at the end **causes all searched words in a line** to be replaced.

So, **the lack of the "g" flag means** only the 1st occurrence of foo on each line where it exists will be removed/replaced.

The "assumption" is you have only one occurrence of foo on each affected line giving the appearance that every foo is removed. Try putting more than one foo on a line, then you will find that not all occurrences are removed.

`:%s/foo//` *covers every line, only the 1st occurrence of foo on each line removed.*

`:%s/foo//g` *covers every line, and every occurrence of foo on each line removed.*

`:s/foo//`  covers only the current line and only the 1st occurrence of foo is removed if foo exists.

`:s/foo//g` covers only the current line and all occurrences of foo on the current line will be removed.

Reference **:help usr_12.txt**    *12.1 Replace a word.*[image: Vim Replace a word help shown:]